# the trait `anchor_lang::AccountSerialize` is not implemented for `Requester

Tags: anchor, rust, cargo

The Requester struct looks like this

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
pub struct Requester {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub oracle: Pubkey,
    pub created_at: i64,
    pub count: u64,
    pub last_updated: i64,
    pub random: [u8; 64],
    pub pkt_id: [u8; 32],
    pub tls_id: [u8; 32],
    pub active_request: bool,
    pub uuid: u64,
    pub bump: u8,
}
```

and this is one of the use case

```
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
        init, 
        seeds = [b"r-seed".as_ref(), authority.key().as_ref(), &uuid.to_le_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 8 + size_of::<Requester>()
    )]
    pub requester: Account<'info, Requester>,
```

but i get this error when i run anchor build

```
 the trait bound `Requester: anchor_lang::AccountSerialize` is not satisfied
   --> /home/icus/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/solrand-0.1.5/src/lib.rs:151:20
    |
151 |     pub requester: Account<'info, Requester>,
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `anchor_lang::AccountSerialize` is not implemented for `Requester`
 pub struct Account<'info, T: AccountSerialize + AccountDeserialize + Owner + Clone> {
    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `anchor_lang::prelude::Account`
```

Any help on how this can be solved will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The `zero_copy` macro doesn't derive AccountSerialize. [It derives](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/ae0131dbb42c142a5ef95e73da70c6780d49d5ad/lang/attribute/account/src/lib.rs#L127) Pod, Zeroable, ZeroCopy, Discriminator, and AccountDeserialize. If you instead replace `Account<'info, Requester>` with `AccountLoader<'info, Requester>`, (docs [here](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/account_loader/struct.AccountLoader.html)) which is intended to be used with ZeroCopy accounts, your program should work.